having a problem with sharp js when runing server
I'm getting the following error message when trying to run my server:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'
Require stack:
- /Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js',
    '/Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/ahmedm.fawzy/dev_nanos/learning/react/projects/exam/exam-app/server/server.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i tried reinstalling sharp but it still did not work i want to know why i get this error

What command are you using to run the server? What node version are you using? Can you share the actual code that's erroring?

can you plz share more details for this
bcz this is not clear question for give and
